# How to access Azure logic app run log by another logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azureportal

I have build an Integration between two systems using Azure Logic Apps. As per some Audit requirements I want to get Logic app run log into a kind of excel report and send it to Audit team by an another scheduled logic app in kind of Excel format.

So basically this is about accessing some Logic App's run log from another logic app..

Can someone provide me a guidance on this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this requirement, I can provide a sample for your reference:

**1.** Create a "Log Analytics workspace" and add "Logic Apps Management" in it, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#install-logic-apps-management-solution).

**2.** Create a new logic app and configure the "Diagnostic settings", please refer to the steps on this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#set-up-azure-monitor-logs).

**3.** After completing the configuration above, please wait for a few minutes and then run your logic app serval times for test (The logs in Log Analytics workspace will be a little bit of a delay, I wait for more than 30 minutes. It just show the logs of running instance which run after 30 minutes of the "Diagnostic settings" deployment).

**4.** Go to your "Log Analytics workspace", click "Workspace summary" --> "Logs".
[image]

There are four query samples for logic app to query the logs, you can also write some other queries to query the logs which you want.
[image]

I just use the third query sample to query the logs distribution by status, we can see there are two success and one failed.
[image]

**5.** Then create another logic app to get the logs and generate the excel. First add "Run query and list results(preview)" action and copy the query sample to the "Query" box.
[image]
[image]

**6.** Run the logic app, we can see the logs result show as below format.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "LogicAppName": "huryLogLogic",
      "NumberOfExecutions": 1,
      "RunStatus": "Failed",
      "Error": "ActionFailed"
    },
    {
      "LogicAppName": "huryLogLogic",
      "NumberOfExecutions": 2,
      "RunStatus": "Succeeded",
      "Error": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

**7.** As I don't know how to generate the excel in logic app, so in my logic app I generated csv instead. Use "[Create CSV table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-csv-table-action)" action to generate the csv.
[image]

**8.** After running the logic app, the logs in csv shown as below. You can transfer the csv to your code or other service and convert it to excel.
[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: Is it possible to get detailed log for each run instance??

Comment: @VajiraPrabuddhaka Sorry I think this requirement can be implemented but I'm not good at the query, does this [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0siMS.png) can meet your requirement ?

Comment: `AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.LOGIC" 
| where Category == "WorkflowRuntime"
| where resource_workflowName_s == "<LA_name>"
| where trackedProperties_Project_number_s != ""
| project resource_workflowName_s, resource_runId_s, trackedProperties_<name>` 
@Hury Shen This code worked for me